# Python matplotlib - doubling the histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Task: save 2 histograms in separate files:
a histogram of ratings and a histogram of years. The data is taken from the ratings.list file.

Problem: The second histogram outputs its own values, and the values of the first histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
    with open('ratings.list', 'r') as reader:
        line = reader.readline()
        while line == '\n' or 'New' not in line and 'Distribution' not in line:
            line = reader.readline()

        line = reader.readline()
        ratings = []
        years = []
        while line != '' and line != '\n' and line != 'BOTTOM 10 MOVIES (1500+ VOTES)':
            columns = line.split()
            initial_tabs = 13
            index = len(columns[0]) + len(columns[1]) + len(columns[2]) + initial_tabs
            title = line[index:len(line)]

            with open('top250_movies.txt', 'a') as writer:
                line = title + '\n'
                writer.write(line)

            ratings.append(columns[2])

            year = line[(line.index('(') + 1):line.index(')')]
            years.append(year)
            years.sort()

            line = reader.readline()
    
        rate_hist = plt.hist(ratings, bins=10)
        plt.title('Ratings')
        plt.xlabel('Ratings')
        plt.ylabel('Movies count')
        ys = rate_hist[0]
        xs = rate_hist[1]
        plt.savefig('ratings.png')
    
        year_hist = plt.hist(years, bins=50)
        plt.title('Years')
        plt.xlabel('Years')
        plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=4)
        plt.ylabel('Movies count')
        ys = year_hist[0]
        xs = year_hist[1]
        plt.savefig('years.png')
    
    
except IOError:
    print('File does not exist')
```

[image: my correct histogram]

[image: incorrect histogram with double rate_hist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `plt.close(fig)` after the first plot save, just before you start the second one.